# Embeding Interactive python plots on static html page with plotly

Tags: python, static, plotly

I am currently trying to create interactive plots in python i can embed in a html static page.
I quickly discovered plotly that does the job very well for most of my interactive plots, but i came up with one issue.

I couldn't find a way with plotly to create an interactive plot that does something as simple as this : create a 2D plot with a line *y = ax + b*  where i can control both parameters a and b using 2 separate
sliders.

This is the equivalent of what i want to achieve but with ipywidget :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from ipywidgets import interact, FloatSlider

def plot_line(a, b):
    y = [a*x_val + b for x_val in x]
    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.ylim(-50, 50)
    plt.grid(True)

x = range(-10, 11)
slider_a = FloatSlider(min=-10, max=10, step=0.1, value=1, description='a:')
slider_b = FloatSlider(min=-10, max=10, step=0.1, value=0, description='b:')

interact(plot_line, a=slider_a, b=slider_b)
plt.show()
```

I did already many plots with one slider with [plotly doc](https://plotly.com/python/sliders/) but I'm stuck with this.

My question is : Is it possible to do what i want with plotly ? If not what other tools can i use to achieve this ?